# How to create an email account on centos 7 with expired cpanel

Tags: linux, email, centos, cpanel, postfix-mta

I have a VM with centos 7 installed and I installed cpanel months ago, but now it is expired. I really need to create some email accounts ASAP, and be able to access them from thunderbird or even redirect them to my gmail account. I tried to follow some tutorials to do this, but I got stuck on the postfix installation, for some reason it can't be installed may be it is the cpanel.

Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to renew your cpanel license and then create the email account. Not sure what you did with postfix installation but I would suggest not to install it as the server has exim installed.

Answer (score -1):

/scripts/addpop mytest@site.net password 50  2>&1

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).